# Binomial Coefficient of a Binomial Coefficient

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

The question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2008128/understanding-the-combinatorial-argument-for-binom-binomn22-3-binom) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1081417/is-there-a-counting-groups-committees-proof-for-the-identity-binom-binomn) refers a neat identity equating the binomial coefficient of a binomial coefficient to another binomial coefficient.

$$\binom {\binom n2}2=3\binom {n+1}4$$

Are there any other similar identities, and is there a systematic way of converting one form to the other?

Comment: $\binom{\binom{n}{3}}{3}$ is a polynomial of degree 9 in $n$, and thus cannot be equal to $\binom{n}{3} - 1$ which is a polynomial of degree 3 in $n$.

Comment: @MeesdeVries - That is correct!

Comment: One comment I can make (but I do not know if that helps you) is that $\binom{\binom{n}{k}}{l}$ is always a polynomial of degree $kl$ in $n$, and meanwhile the binomial coefficients $\binom{n}{0},\binom{n}{1},\ldots,\binom{n}{kl}$ form a basis for the space of polynomials in $n$ of degree at most $kl$, so you can always write the former as a linear combination of the latter.

Comment: @MeesdeVries - Thanks. That's an important observation.

Comment: Several years ago there was a question here about binomial coefficients with a binomial coefficient as upper number, with a reference to a paper that dealt extensively with such objects. Unfortunately, I’ve only a dim recollection of the question and paper and have so far been unable to track down either.